# RSpec request spec for user_login via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-request

I'm trying to write a request spec for my `user_login` API, but can't figure out how to get a valid user that doesn't return a wrong username or password `401` invalid error.

Here is my spec:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do
  subject(:user) do
    Program.create!(name: 'test', gender: 'Female', goal_id: '1', experience_id: '1')
    User.create!(email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678', password_confirmation: '12345678', goal_id: '1', experience_level_id: '1', gender: 'Female')
  end

  it "is logged in" do
    post "/api/v1/login", user_login: {email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678' }
    response.status.should be(201)
  end
```

My understanding was that creating a User in the subject line would mean that my test would run against that user. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And Here is the answer

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "sessions" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:program)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

    describe "user" do
      it "is logged in" do
        post "/api/v1/login", user_login: {email: @user.email, password: @user.password }
        response.status.should be(201)
      end
    end
end
```

I'm not totally sure what's different than what I was doing in the question. I replaced the `subject` block with a `before` block and moved the creation of the program and user into Factories.